# Struct methods as FFI callbacks

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm working on a plugin for an existing host application. The application provides a native C SDK that I connect to from Rust with FFI bindings generated with `bindgen`. The SDK relies heavily on callback functions to inform my plugin of state changes and user interactions.

My plugin on the Rust side is basically a `struct`holding the relevant data. All functionality is built into methods of this struct.

My challenge are those function callbacks needed by the SDK.

I can easily create static functions and hand them over to the host application:

```rust
// function to set callback function in FFI lib
fn set_callback(callback_fn: fn(usize)) {
    let ptr = callback_fn as *const ();
    unsafe {
        // transmute the fn ptr into a C-style fn
        std::mem::transmute::<*const (), Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(usize)>>(ptr);
        // this can now be handed over as the callback via FFI
        // ...
    }
}

// Rust function to be used as callback
fn my_callback(val: usize) {
    println!("{}", val);
}

set_callback(my_callback);
```

Those functions just don't have access to my struct and thus the data and functionality stored there. So I need to use methods of my struct.

If I convert those static functions into methods of my struct, I can't use them as callback anymore:

```rust
struct dummy {}

impl dummy {
    fn set_callback(&mut self, callback_fn: fn(usize)) {
        let ptr = callback_fn as *const ();
        unsafe {
            // transmute the fn ptr into a C-style fn
            std::mem::transmute::<*const (), Option<unsafe extern "C" fn(usize)>>(ptr);
            // this can now be handed over as the callback via FFI
            // ...
        }
    }
    fn my_callback(&self, val: usize) {
        // do something
    }

    fn init(&mut self) {
        self.set_callback(self.my_callback);
    }
}

let mut dummy_instance = dummy {};
dummy_instance.init();
```

```rust
error[E0615]: attempted to take value of method `my_callback` on type `&mut dummy`
   --> src/main.rs:18:36
    |
 18 |             self.set_callback(self.my_callback);
    |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ method, not a field
    |
help: use parentheses to call the method
    |
 18 |             self.set_callback(self.my_callback(_));
    |                                               ^^^
```

Seems that I'd have to use a closure encapsulating that function call. This creates the next obstacle for me, as I can't easily hand over that closure via FFI to call from C. I could wrap it like this:

```rust
use std::ffi::c_void;

type Callback<T> = unsafe extern "C" fn(*mut c_void, x: T) -> T;

fn c_like_closure<F, T>(_: &mut F) -> Callback<T>
where
    F: FnMut(T) -> T,
{
    unsafe extern "C" fn invoke<Q, S>(state: *mut c_void, x: S) -> S
    where
        Q: FnMut(S) -> S,
    {
        let func = &mut *(state as *mut Q);
        func(x)
    }

    invoke::<F, T>
}

struct Dummy {}

impl Dummy {
    fn my_callback(&self, val: usize) -> usize {
        val
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut my_plugin = Dummy {};
    let mut cb = |val: usize| my_plugin.my_callback(val);

    let fn_ptr = c_like_closure(&mut cb);
    let g = unsafe { fn_ptr(&mut cb as *mut _ as *mut c_void, 123) };
}
```

The caveat is, that I'd have to somehow hand over the context. And the SDK I have to use doesn't offer any function parameters that would allow me top pass the context back and forth.

I've found `libffi`crate that seems to be able to wrap a closure and hand it over via FFI. The above example can be altered as following:

```rust
use libffi::high::arity1::Closure1;
...
fn main() {

    let mut my_plugin = Dummy {};
    let mut cb = |val: usize| my_plugin.my_callback(val);

    let closure = Closure1::new(&cb);
    let fn_ptr = closure.code_ptr();
    unsafe {
        fn_ptr(123);
    }
}
```

Nice!

Until I try to do it from inside my struct, within my `init_plugin`method. There I can't easily create a closure using `self`:

```rust
struct Dummy {
    closure: Option<Box<Fn(usize) -> usize>>,
}

impl Dummy {
    fn my_callback(&self, val: usize) -> usize {
        println!("{}", val);
        val
    }

    fn init_plugin(&mut self) {
        self.closure = Some(Box::new(|val: usize| self.my_callback(val)));
    }
}
```

```rust
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> src/main.rs:64:38
   |
63 |     fn init_plugin(&mut self) {
   |                    --------- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
64 |         self.closure = Some(Box::new(|val: usize| self.my_callback(val)));
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...is captured here, requiring it to live as long as `'static`
```

Looks like I'm stuck on my path with closures… The only other option I see would be some static intermediate functions that get a reference to my plugin struct from somewhere and then call the methods on that like this:

```rust
let my_plugin = Dummy{};

Dummy::my_callback(my_plugin, 123);
```

But that would require `my_plugin`to become a global variable, which doesn't sound too convincing to me…

It's quite obvious, that I'm not the only one, trying to work with callbacks via FFI. I wonder how this can be solved without giving up on Rust's principles and advantages.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me: for this SDK, if you were writing a C plugin, how would the SDK have access to the struct? Would you pass around a pointer or an opaque value? Or some other way?

Comment: @ddulaney The SDK doesn't need access to the struct. It calls member functions of that struct, that then call SDK's plain C functions to trigger action. E.g. user makes input → trigger `gotInput()` function in my code → trigger `display()` function in SDK. The SDK samples use plain C functions and a global variable to store state. That global var for state is the thing I'm not convinced of doing in Rust is a good idea.